# Why do these TikZ intersections scale incorrectly?

Tags: tikz-pgf, scaling, intersections

In the following MWE, the shaded region scales incorrectly. The problem seems to involve the intersection calculations. What's the problem here?

Here's the MWE, without scaling:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

    % axes
    \draw[->,name path=yaxis] (0,0) -- (0,1.2);
    \draw[->,name path=xaxis] (0,0) -- (1.2,0);
    \coordinate (origin) at (0,0);

    % diagonal
    \draw[name path=diag] (0,1) -- (1,0);

    % intersection points
    \node[coordinate, name intersections={of=diag and yaxis}] (diagy) at (intersection-1) {};
    \node[coordinate, name intersections={of=diag and xaxis}] (diagx) at (intersection-1) {};

    % fill
    \fill[opacity=0.1] (origin) -- (diagy) -- (diagx);

    \end{tikzpicture}   

\end{document}
```

Correct figure, again without scaling:

[image]

Now if I change

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
```

to

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
```

I get the following:

[image]

If I replace

```
\node[coordinate, name intersections={of=diag and yaxis}] (diagy) at (intersection-1) {};
\node[coordinate, name intersections={of=diag and xaxis}] (diagx) at (intersection-1) {};
```

with

```
\node[coordinate] (diagy) at (0,5) {};
\node[coordinate] (diagx) at (5,0) {};
```

the figure scales correctly, which is why I think the intersection calculation is what's causing the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Try to close the path: `(origin) -- (diagy) -- (diagx)--cycle;`

Comment: No luck -- same thing happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
% intersection points
\path[name intersections={of=diag and yaxis,by={A}}];
\path[name intersections={of=diag and xaxis,by={B}}];
```

to define inter sections and then

```
% fill
\fill[opacity=0.1] (origin) -- (A) -- (B);
```

Here is the full code

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]

    % axes
    \draw[->,name path global=yaxis] (0,0) -- (0,1.2);
    \draw[->,name path global=xaxis] (0,0) -- (1.2,0);
    \coordinate (origin) at (0,0);

    % diagonal
    \draw[name path global=diag] (0,1) -- (1,0);

    % intersection points
    \path[name intersections={of=diag and yaxis,by={A}}];
    \path[name intersections={of=diag and xaxis,by={B}}];

    % fill
    \fill[opacity=0.1] (origin) -- (A) -- (B);

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect. Can you explain what the problem was with the original code, and why the new code works?

Answer (score 3):

As already explained here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/218292/9335, there is probably a bug in `node at` used with intersections and transformation (the transformation seems to be applied twice on the intersection points).

You can simply replace `\node at (point)` with `\path (point) node`, and it shoud be ok.
Here is the corrected code.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    % axes
    \draw[->,name path=yaxis] (0,0) -- (0,1.2);
    \draw[->,name path=xaxis] (0,0) -- (1.2,0);
    \coordinate (origin) at (0,0);

    % diagonal
    \draw[name path=diag] (0,1) -- (1,0);

    % intersection points
    \path[coordinate, name intersections={of=diag and yaxis}] (intersection-1) node (diagy) {};
    \path[coordinate, name intersections={of=diag and xaxis}] (intersection-1) node (diagx) {};

    % fill
    \fill[opacity=0.1] (origin) -- (diagy) -- (diagx);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: OK, glad to know it's not just something I'm misunderstanding. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, this works too. @user43963's code is a little more efficient so I'll probably go with that.

Comment: @grendelsdad I agree with you. The "correct" code is this of user43963. I put this here just to explain what is the problem, and after the previous answer was accepted ;)